# $f(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients, $f(2i)= f(2+i)=0$...

Tags: polynomials

$f(x)= x^4 + ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is a polynomial with real coefficients and $f(2i)= f(2+i)=0$, what is the value of $a+b+c+d $?

This was a question I saw on internet but I don't want its solution, I just want to ask something about it. $2i$ and $2+i$ would  be roots of $f(x)$ but the one who solved it also said that $-2i$ and $2-i$ were roots of it and I couldn't understand why, could you explain me please?

Comment: for polynomials with real coefficients, all complex roots come in conjugate pairs. if $2i$ is a root, then $-2i$ is also a root. If $2+i$ is a root, so does $2-i$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a polynomial with real coefficients and if $z \in \mathbb C$, then we have

$f( \overline{z})= \overline{f(z)}$.

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: I think that yes but is there a way to show this?

Comment: @Vmimi First show that $\overline{z^n} = {\overline{z}}^n$ by induction, using the fact that $\overline{zw} = \overline{z}\overline{w}$. It then follows that $\overline{az^n} = \overline{a}\overline{z^n} = a{\overline{z}}^n$ when $a$ is real. Finally, you just need to complete the proof for sums of these monomial terms, again using induction, and the fact that $\overline{z + w} = \overline{z} + \overline{w}$.

Comment: Also when you say that $z \in \mathbb C$, does this mean that it has to have an imaginary part?